# Kafka Spout consumer and another consumer running inside Spring not able to run simultaneously

Tags: bigdata, apache-kafka, apache-storm

My application accepts a url containing the data it needs to process through a rest service it exposes using spring.

Each time it receives a url from which to accept data, the application

- Sends the url to a DataReady Consumer on the topic "DataReady"
- The DataReady consumer downloads the data from the url and uses a kafka producer to send it to a storm topology on the topic "DataProcess"

The processed data is accepted by a Kafka Spout inside the storm topology. This is only a test system so all the code is running in localhost with only one partition, one broker and a replication factor of 1.

The problem is that I cannot get both the KafkaSpout and the DataReady consumer to connect to zookeeper simultaneously. Both the KafkaSpout and the DataReady Consumer running inside Tomcat are able to connect to Zookeeper when running standalone.

I am using **apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating** and **kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1**.

My storm.yaml file has the following configuration

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "localhost"

nimbus.host: "localhost"
```

The exception thrown from storm when it is run after Tomcat is

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:     org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
        at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:83) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
        at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:45) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
        at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:118) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$eval3848$fn__3849$fn__3864$fn__3893.invoke(executor.clj:562) ~[na:na]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__384.invoke(util.clj:433) ~[na:na]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
        at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:62) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
        at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:54) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
```

When I run storm first and Tomcat later, I get a NoNode exception. Can anyone please help me understand why I might be getting this behavior?

Comment: Are you running the topology using a LocalCluster?

Comment: No, I am submitting the Storm topology the usual way after starting Zookeeper, Nimbus and Supervisor.

Comment: Did you confirm that zookeeper is indeed accepting connection from that machine by e.g. doing telnet x.x.x.x 2181?

Comment: @EnnoShioji I get the following message
    `Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: Hm sorry I don't have more suggestions then. Hope somebody gives an answer.

Comment: did you guys able to resolve it?